# How do I aggregate an array of maps in Java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, data-transform

I have a dataset "events" that includes an array of maps. I want to turn it into one map which is the aggregation of the amounts and counts

Currently, I'm running the following statement:

```
events.select(functions.col(“totalAmounts)).collectAsList()
```

which returns the following:

```
[
    [
        Map(totalCreditAmount -> 10, totalDebitAmount -> 50)
    ],
    [
        Map(totalCreditAmount -> 50, totalDebitAmount -> 100)
    ]   
]
```

I want to aggregate the amounts and counts and have it return:

```
[
    Map(totalCreditAmount -> 60, totalDebitAmount -> 150)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `explode` function on the array of map column to get the
result into an flattened array and then performing the `sum` aggregate

```sql
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = events.select(F.explode("totalAmounts").alias("flattenedAmounts"))
df = df.select(F.explode(df.flattenedAmounts)).groupBy("key").agg(F.sum("value").alias("value"))

final_result_as_map = df.rdd.collectAsMap()
```

The `final_result_as_map` must be of the shape and form you are expecting.